# Strategy Pattern with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a workflow in which I need to use particular service class based on some run time data.

For eg. I have a `SendEmailCommand` with a dependency of `IEmailService` with 2 implementations of `MandrillEmailService` and `SmtpEmailService`.

The `SendEmailCommand` will determine which implementation of `IEmailService` it uses at run time.

Each Email Service implementation has its own dependencies, which is wired up by Simple Injector.

I'm not sure how `SendEmailCommand` will determine what implementation (`IEmailService`) to use or how to wire up those services with run time data.

Some code:

*SendEmailCommand.cs* handler

```
public void Handle(SendEmail command) {
  IEmailService service;

  if(/* some condition */) {
    service = // What to do here?
  } else {
    service = // What to do here?
  }
}
```

Service can be substituted with a strategy I'm guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious solution (to me) is to define a new abstraction that allows dispatching to the mail service implementation while supplying the runtime data to it. This might look like this:

```
interface IMailServiceDispatcher
{
    void Send([runtime data], [mail service arguments]);
}
```

This allows your command handler to become:

```
private readonly IEmailServiceDispatcher dispatcher;
public void Handle(SendEmail command) {
  var data = /* runtime data */
  this.dispatcher.Send(data, /* mail service parameters */);
}
```

Now you can create an implementation for `IMailServiceDispatcher` that might look as follows:

```
class EmailServiceDispatcher : IEmailServiceDispatcher
{
    IMailService man; IMailService smtp;
    public EmailServiceDispatcher(IMailService man, IMailService smtp) { ... }

    public void Send(runtimeData, parameters) =>
        GetService(runtimedData).Send(parameters);

    private IMailService GetService(runtimeData) =>
        /* some condition using runtime data */ ? man : smtp;
}
```

You can wire this all up as follows:

```
container.Register<IMailServiceDispatcher, MailServiceDispatcher>();
container.RegisterConditional<IMailService, MandrillEmailService>(WithParamName("man"));
container.RegisterConditional<IMailService, SmtpEmailService>(WithParamName("smtp"));

// Helper method
private static Predicate<PredicateContext> WithParamName(string name) =>
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == name;
```